# How to use useState within a promise.then()?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to set a state within a promise.then() block and I'm confused on why it's not working.

```
const [rules, setRules] React.useState(<h1>hi</h1>);
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(false);

const getRules = () => {
  apicall.promise().then((res) => {
    var rules = null;
    ...
    rules = <h1>hello</h1>;
    ...
    return rules;
  }).then((rulesComp) => {
    setRules(rulesComp);
  });
}

const SvgButton = ({node}: any) => {
  return (
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20">
      <div onClick={() => {getRules(); setModalVisible(true);}}>
        <mySVG />
      </div>
    </foreignObject>     
  )
}

return (

    <><div>
       <SvgButton> is shown here
    </div>

    <Modal
      onDismiss={() => setModalVisible(false)}
      visible={modalVisible}
      closeAriaLabel="Close modal"
      footer="Modal footer"
      header="Modal title"
    >
      {rules}
    </Modal></>
);
```

How can I make it so that the proper `rules` renders? Because right now it's just constantly showing the initial state.

Comment: The code in the question, as-is, should work, assuming the API succeeds (though you really shouldn't store components in state) - I think the question needs more details to be answerable

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added some more details but there isn't much more in the code. The API call itself is working as I can console.log the responses. I also tried just setting a global variable for "rules" instead of state but it wasn't working either

Comment: The `apicall.promise()` return native `Promise`? If so I can't really find why it is not working for you. If you can reproduce it in stackblitz or something like that we might be able to help you.

Comment: Not related probably, but declaring a component inside another component can cause problems